# difficulty with arrays

Tags: java

I am a bit stuck so if anyone has a spare moment it would be a great help for me. I am using eclipse and the program is compiling and running. but there is a runtime error.
in the array {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1} I want to print {2, 2, 2} which is the numbers with the highest repeating times in the array. What I am getting is: 
0
1
0
0
3
0
2
2
0

Thank you guys and here is my code.

```
public class SameIndexInArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] array = {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1};
        int[] subarray = new int[array.length]; //store the values should be {2, 2, 2}

        int max = 1;
        int total = 1;

        for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] != array[i + 1])
            {
                max = 1;
            }
            else if(array[i] == array[i + 1])
            {
                max++;
                total = max;
                subarray[i] = array[i]; // here is the issue
            }
            System.out.println(subarray[i]);
        }
        //System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Comment: ignore that, i see what you're trying to do now :)

Comment: no it should be only {2,2,2} because they are in a row one after the other

Comment: you need to take care of `i`, and `max`. The logic  is flawed.

Comment: Thank you all for your time I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
 int[] ar = { 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
    int max=0,
        maxStart=0,
        count=1;

    for(int i=1; i<ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i-1] == ar[i]) {
            count++;
            if(count > max) {
                max = count;
                maxStart = i-count+1;
            }
        }else {
            count=1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sub array begins from " + maxStart);

    for(int i = maxStart; i < maxStart + max; i++) {
        System.out.print(ar[i] + " ");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only store facultatively into subarray, so you should define a separate counter (let's say j) for subarray index counting, and say subarray[j++] = array[i]. And, you shouldn't output subarray for each index of array, so move that println into the second if clause.

Comment: Alternatively you could also do a sort such as a bubble sort http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/arrayexamples/bubbleSort.shtml and then print from array.length backwards while the elements are the same.

Answer (score 2):

see if this works

```
    int[] array = {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1};

    int frequency = 0;
    int num = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++)
    {
        int lfreq = 1;
        int lnum = array[i];
        while(array[i] == array[i+1]){
            lfreq++;
            i++;
        }
        if(lfreq >= frequency){
            frequency = lfreq;
            num = lnum;
        }

    }
    int[] subarray = new int[frequency];
    for(int i=0; i < frequency; i++)
        subarray[i] = num;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subarray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another index but "i"
you can't relate to 2 arrays with the same index

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that all values in subarray are initialized with 0 and you only edit the values when there is an actual sequence, starting with the second element.

The whole subarray is unneccessary. Just save the start index and the length of the subquery ;)

What I mean is something like this:

```
int[] array = {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1};

int startIndex = 0;
int length = 0;

int longestIndex = 0;
int longestLength = 0;

for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++)
{
    if(array[i] != array[i + 1])
    {
        if (length > longestLength) {
            longestLength = length;
            longestIndex = startIndex;
        }
        startIndex = i;
        length = 1;
    }
    else if(array[i] == array[i + 1])
    {
        length++;
    }
}

if (length > longestLength) {
    longestLength = length;
    longestIndex = startIndex;
}
```

Now you that you know where your longest sequence starts and how long it is you can build your new array:

```
int[] sequence = new int[longestLength];
for (int i = 0; i < longestLength; i++) {
    sequence[i] = array[i + startIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are inserting at an index position "i" into  subarray.
For example, 
The second time the loop runs.

`array[1] == array[2]` is true and

```
subarray[i] = array[i];
```

runs. So at this moment the contents of subarray is {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}. Note that arrays are initialized to 0 by default.

This is how you could do it.

```
int[] array = {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1};
         //store the values should be {2, 2, 2}

        int max = 1;
        int total = 1;
        int value = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] != array[i + 1])
            {
                max = 1;
            }
            else if(array[i] == array[i + 1])
            {
                max++;
                total = max;
                value = array[i];
            }

        }
        int[] subarray = new int[total];
        for(int i=0; i<total; i++)
            subarray[i] = value;
```